# Handling wcf services from nodejs

Tags: wcf, web-services, node.js, soap, svc

I am trying to access soap *URL*,I came across different file types i.e. `.asmx` and `.svc`. I used the node-soap module for handling `.asmx` services. For `.svc` I came across `wcf.js` below is the code

```
var BasicHttpBinding = require('wcf.js').BasicHttpBinding
, Proxy = require('wcf.js').Proxy
, binding = new BasicHttpBinding()
, proxy = new Proxy(binding, "https://webservice.kareo.com/services/soap/2.1/")
, message = '<Envelope xmlns=' +
        '"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">' +
             '<Header />' +
               '<Body>' +
                 '<GetData xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">' +
                   '<value>GetAppointments</value>' +
                 '</GetData>' +
                '</Body>' +
           '</Envelope>'

proxy.send(message, "http://www.kareo.com/api/schemas/KareoServices/GetAppointments",       function(response, ctx) {
console.log(response)
});
```

I could not understand what has to be passed as message as an input for `wcf` web service.

Can Anyone provide me some idea regarding this? It will be really helpful.

Advance Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message should contain the raw soap wcf expects. You can get it by using WCF logging or Fiddler on an existing working c# client.

Comment: you have pasted above a working example... you just need to change the message per your needs, you can ask the service vendor for an exmaple